# Thread is not terminated using conditional TimerTask

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I test a simple Timer and TimerTask based on Reminder example from [this article](http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

The only difference is I use conditional if before timer.cancel(). In the original example, the thread stop as expected but in my code, it does not stop. What's wrong?

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ConditionalReminder {
    Timer           timer;

    public ConditionalReminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        int counter;

        public void run() {
            counter++;
            System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
            if(counter==100) 
            {
                timer.cancel(); //should terminate thread
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ConditionalReminder(2);
        System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it run forever? Or just once?

Comment: It runs forever Thilo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-) schedules a task to execute *once*, after the provided delay. If you want it to repeat, you'll need to use [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask, long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-). For example:

```
int delay = 0;
int interval = seconds * 1000;
timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), delay, interval);
```

Comment: Ah I see, silly me. Thank you very much for your prompt response!